# For how long are temporary image URLs from UIImagePickerController valid?

Tags: ios

Does the system make any guarantees regarding this? I'm only concerned about iOS > 13.

edit: additionally, is there a way to obtain a persistent filepath?

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? It's a programming question, I can't find anything in the docs, and there's really no relevant code to be added, as this is a straightforward question about an API...

Answer (score 0):

You should assume that the URL is valid only during the execution of the delegate method. If you need the image data to persist on disk, moving it (during the delegate method) is up to you.